# Add SlideDown effect on modal close CSS

Tags: css, css-animations

I have this style for my modal and I wonder where and how do I reverse slideUp effect on modal close.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
       modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: black;
    color: white; 
    -webkit-animation: slideIn 0.4s;
    animation: slideIn 0.4s;   
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0} 
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<span class="close">&times;</span>

<p>Some content here</p>

</div>
```

Basically I want to modal closing same way it is showing (same animation on modal open and modal close, pure CSS only), can someone help me with that?

Comment: Seems like you should use a transition instead of keyframes animation, but can't tell until you create a [mcve]. [Have a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586143/css-animation-vs-transition), it explains the difference between transitions and keyframes

Comment: I updated the question @Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a transition that is applied when you add and remove a class:

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  transition: opacity 0.4s, bottom 0.4s;  /* animate these properties */
  opacity: 1;                             /* open state is shown */
}

.modal.closed {
  opacity: 0;     /* close state is hidden and off screen */
  bottom: -300px;
}

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal closed">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <p>Some content here</p>
</div>

<div id="myBtn">click me</div>

<script>
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  btn.onclick = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();                    /* stop event bubbling up to window */
    modal.classList.remove("closed");
  }
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.classList.add("closed");
  }
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target != modal) {
      modal.classList.add("closed");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I notice that `show` is happened as expected, but `hiding` is to match quickier than `show`

Comment: That's because your animation is 0.4seconds and you move your banner 300px. The show is exactly the same speed as the hide