# How to fix CSS "transition" un-hover an element?

Tags: css

I have a nav bar on the left corner of the page. the nav bar is already set on `margin-left: -120px;` on hover, it transforms to `105px`, so I would like to have smooth back when un-hover the element.

I have tried to use `transition` on the ul, ul li, ul li a, putting them in different classes. nothing really working with me...

```
/* ----- NAVBAR ----- */

ul {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
}

.li1{
    animation: move1 2s;
}
.li2{
    animation: move1 3s;
}
.li3{
    animation: move1 4s;
}
.li4{
    animation: move1 5s;
}
.li5{
    animation: move1 6s;
}

ul li {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left: -120px;
}

ul li a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    background: #1a2738;
    width: 140px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background: #1a2738;
    color: #fff;
    animation: move2 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes move1 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(-50px);
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 100;
        transform: translate(105px);
    }
}

@keyframes move2 {
    100% {
        transform: translate(105px);
    }
}
```

I hope to know what's the actual problem, help please, thanks!

Comment: use a transition instead of a keyframes animation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586143/css-animation-vs-transition

Comment: Motaz, please provide the relevant HTML code as well. It is going to be a lot helpful to everyone on here to see the HTML and CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over complicating the CSS using keyframes you can use a transition instead see below code:

```
/* ----- NAVBAR ----- */

ul {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
}

ul li {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left: -120px;
}

ul li a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    background: #1a2738;
    width: 140px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
    transform: translateX(-50px);
}

ul li a:hover {
    background: #1a2738;
    color: #fff;
    transform: translateX(105px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple slide out and slide back in effect, one way to approach it is to simple use `transform: transitionX(-120px)` on your `ul` element, and just readjust the value from -120px to 0px on the hover of the `ul`, like so:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #ececec;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 600ms;
  transform: translateX(-120px);
}

ul:hover {
  transform: translateX(0px); //you can adjust this measurement unit to whatever value you wish, such as 105px
}

ul li {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

ul li a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    background: #1a2738;
    width: 140px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```