# The problem with scrolling and fixing the nav bar at a certain X

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a problem.
When scrolling the page by 124 pixels, my Navigation Bar becomes sticky and is fixed on top of the screen.

```
 const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      setScroll(window.scrollY > 124);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <nav
      className={
        scroll
          ? "sticky z-50 top-0 bg-blue-800 py-3 border-b-2 border-blue-950 animate-fade-up animate-duration-300 animate-ease-in-out shadow-2xl"
          : "bg-blue-800"
      }
    >
   </nav>
```

But I also set padding by Y - 3rem, and now, when I return to the position UP to 124 pixels, I have a page bounce. So I don't understand how I can fix this?

I also attached a video to make it easier for you to understand

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRp8mlowc5Q

Comment: Can you use the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition `transition` instead of `animate`? 

Comment: Does it really matter?

Comment: I would expect you to use position absolute.

Comment: Do you have a `box-sizing:border-box`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20590319/2569323 . 

Comment: yes i have box-sizing: border-box

Comment: Can i see your `animate-fade-up` class? Are you sure there is -- not -- an `animate-fade-down` class missing? 

Comment: these are just animations from tailwindcss I'm just worried about page bounce when I did padding for nav bar 3 rem, there is no bounce page without this padding